# Looping Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

How can I avoid 'debug' error in my current script of VBA? I've created below script for automation where my it automatic picks up supplier email address listed in specific cell and sends out email. However, sometime it shows the debug error when the email address is not found or even its listed in the cell.

I've used "**Indirect**" function to avoid incorrect values in this cell. Can someone please suggest me a way to avoid debug error and it move on to the next one if the email is not found?

The error line is: `With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope .Introduction = "Body of an email" .Item.To = Range("A5").Value`, occurs when `Range("A5").Value` is **`#N/A`**.

The current script (part only) is below:

```
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

        With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope ' <-- ERROR LINE

          .Introduction = "Body of an email"
          .Item.To = Range("A5").Value ' <-- ERROR WHEN IT's "#N/A"
          .Item.Subject = "subject"
          .Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "inquiry@company.com"
          .Item.send

        End With
```

Comment: I don't really feel like reading through your entire code to see where your error is tbh. If you want to give us the _line_ providing your error, with your exact error code, then I might change my mind.

Comment: 'With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope

  .Introduction = "Body of an email"      
  .Item.To = Range("A5").Value
  .Item.Subject = "subject"
  .Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "inquiry@company.com"
  .Item.send

End With'

Comment: Other than potential errors by Worksheet & Range selection, you need to fix the formulas from row 5 of A column. Without any insight on your data and/or formulas, no one can resolve this error. Please **edit** your post instead adding things in comment.

Comment: Hi @PatricK.. Thanks for updating the script.. I've removed the extra lines and kept only the one that needs help. I'm still new to all these and still trying to find my way in this stack world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two errors here.

WRT to the first error (at `With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope`), since you didn't provide any further details (like what error was reported by the computer!!) it will be almost impossible to help you (unless your expectation is that random strangers from the Internet will come to your house or place of work at any odd hours of the day or night to look at your computer).

---

WRT to the second error, even though you didn't include any further details about the error itself, you seem to have identified the conditions under which it occurs. This is an excellent first step (although it would have been extremely useful if you included the exact error message). However, let's see what we can do with this.

I wasn't able to find official documentation confirming this, but I am guessing that the `Item` property can hold an object of type [**MailItem**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-object-outlook) from the Office Outlook type library. **MailItem** has a [**To** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-to-property-outlook), which expects a `String` -- a sequence of characters:

However, when the cell contains `#N/A`, the value returned from from the `Value` property is an `Error` object, which doesn't fit into a `String`.

You can check whether a cell value is a `String` or an `Error` using the `Typename` function:

```
' Cell A1 has an email; cell A2 has #N/A in it

' prints abc@example.com
Debug.Print activesheet.Range("a1").Value

' prints String
Debug.Print TypeName(activesheet.Range("a1").Value)

' prints Error 2042
Debug.Print activesheet.Range("a2").Value

' prints Error
Debug.Print TypeName(activesheet.Range("a2").Value)
```

You could check if the cell has an actual email address, and only then generate the email message:

```
If TypeName(Range("A5").Value) = "String" Then

    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = "Body of an email"
      .Item.To = Range("A5").Value
      .Item.Subject = "subject"
      .Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "inquiry@company.com"
      .Item.send
    End With

End If
```